# How to use system call 9 (sbrk) for dynamic memory allocation in MIPS

Tags: sorting, mips

I have an assignment which is to write comb sort in MIPS. The user is going to enter the array and of course its size. When searching for heap allocation, I found the system call 9. However, I couldn't find the way to use it. I wrote this:

```
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, message1    # prints the first message 
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 5           # reads the size for the array        
    syscall
    
    mul $t0, $v0, 4     # because array contains integer, I change them into bytes
    la $a0, $t0         # allocate the size of the array in the heap
    li $v0, 9           # now, $v0 has the address of allocated memory
    syscall
    
    move $v1, $v0       # Because systemcall uses $vo register, I move it to $v1 keep it safe.
    
create_array:    
    la $a0, message2    # prints the first message
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall

    li   $s0, 0         # $s1 is the index, and loop induction variable
    li   $s1, 5         # $s1 is the sentinel value for the loop
        
Loop1:  
    bge  $s0, $s1, End_Loop1

    li $v0, 5           # Read integer values
    syscall
    
    mul  $t3, $s0, 4    # $t3 is the offset
    add  $t4, $t3, $t0  # $t4 is the address of desired index
    sw   $v0, ($t4)     # store the value in the array
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    # increment the index        
    j    Loop1

End_Loop1:
```

And I get this error:

```
la": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la $t1,($t2)
```

How can I use it? and Is this the right way to create an array?

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: @Michael "la $a0, $t0  # allocate the size of the array in the heap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
la $a0, $t0     # allocate the size of the array in the heap
```

with

```
move $a0, $t0
```

The `la` instruction's purpose is to [L]oad the [A]ddress of a symbol into a register. For example:

```
la $a0, message1    # prints the first message
```

would load the address of `message1` into register `$a0`. `la` is actually a pseudo-instruction which in this case translates into:

```
lui $a0, message1/0x10000       # load the upper halfword of the address
ori $a0, $a0, message1%0x10000  # OR in the lower halfword of the address
```

As you can imagine it doesn't make sense to try to load the address of another register, since registers don't have addresses.

While we're on the subject of MIPS pseudo-instructions: `move` is also one of them, and the above `move $a0, $t0` instruction translates into something like `add $a0, $0, $t0`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, replace **$t0** with **$v1**. $t0 just holds the total byte allocated in the heap but you need $v1 which is the beginning addres of the array in the heap.
It should be like:

```
add  $t4, $t3, $v1      # $t4 is the address of desired index
```